# iOS, UISwipeGestureRecognizer on Custom UIView - not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am unable to have a successful UISwipeGestureRecognizer set onto my custom view.
I have tested on the main `self.view` with success, but i cannot get it to work on my custom.

**Parent.m**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISummaryChartView *chartView;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.chartView = [[UISummaryChartView alloc] initWithWidth:self.view.frame.size.width andHeight:self.view.frame.size.height withView:self.view];
    [self.chartView openBox];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGest = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDetected:)];
    [swipeGest setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGest];
}

-(void)swipeDetected: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender{
    NSLog(@"swiped..");
    if(self.chartView.frame.size.height > 50){
        //chart view is open
        NSLog(@"closing");
        [self.chartView closeBox];
    }
}
```

**UISummaryChartView.h**

```
UISummaryChartView : UIView

-(id) initWithWidth:(CGFloat)inWidth andHeight:(CGFloat)inHeight withView: (UIView*) theView{
    self = [super init];

    self.mainView = theView;
    //super view bounds
    self.viewWidth = inWidth;
    self.viewHeight = inHeight;
    CGFloat startx = 2;
    CGFloat starty = 0;
    self.width = self.viewWidth - 10;
    self.height = (self.viewHeight / 100) * 50;
    self.view1Frame = CGRectMake(startx, starty, self.width, self.height);

    return self;
}

-(void) openBox{
    CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake(0, 10, self.mainView.frame.size.width, 1);
    self.view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:startFrame];
    [self.mainView addSubview:self.view1];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
        [self.view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(float)126/255.0 green:(float)35/255.0 blue:(float)32/255.0 alpha:1]];
        self.view1.frame = self.view1Frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];
}
```

Comment: do you want to close your custom view with similar gesture?

Comment: Yes, a swipe up on the view to close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 things to do to make this work:

First, your `UIView` subclass has no `frame` or `bounds` because you used `init` and not `initWithFrame:`

Second, you have to set a `delegate` on your main `UIViewController` and implement the `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` method. This works:

in `UISummaryCharView.m`

```
#import "UISummaryChartView.h"

@implementation UISummaryChartView

@synthesize mainView;

-(id) initWithWidth:(CGFloat)inWidth andHeight:(CGFloat)inHeight withView: (UIView*) theView{
    self = [super initWithFrame:theView.frame]; // THIS IS IMPORTANT
    self.mainView = theView;
    //super view bounds
    self.viewWidth = inWidth;
    self.viewHeight = inHeight;
    CGFloat startx = 2;
    CGFloat starty = 0;
    self.width = self.viewWidth - 10;
    self.height = (self.viewHeight / 100) * 50;
    self.view1Frame = CGRectMake(startx, starty, self.width, self.height);
    NSLog(@"frame %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
    NSLog(@"bounds %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
    return self;
}

-(void) openBox{

    CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake(0, 10, self.mainView.frame.size.width, 1);
    self.view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:startFrame];
    [self.mainView addSubview:self.view1];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
        [self.view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(float)126/255.0 green:(float)35/255.0 blue:(float)32/255.0 alpha:1]];
        self.view1.frame = self.view1Frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"frame %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
        NSLog(@"bounds %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
    }];
}


-(void)closeBox{
    NSLog(@"close box");
    // your closeBox method
}

@end
```

in `Parent.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.chartView = [[UISummaryChartView alloc] initWithWidth:self.view.frame.size.width andHeight:self.view.frame.size.height withView:self.view];
    [self.chartView openBox];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGest = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDetected:)];
    [swipeGest setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];

    [[self view] addSubview:self.chartView];

    self.chartView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.chartView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGest];
    swipeGest.delegate = self;


}

-(void)swipeDetected: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender{
    NSLog(@"swiped..");
    if(self.chartView.frame.size.height > 50){
        //chart view is open
        NSLog(@"closing");
        [self.chartView closeBox];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    NSLog(@"shouldReceiveTouch?");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Genius! good tip on the frame issue, i hadn't realised that. Also the adding the chartView to self's subviews was a key step i missed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate gesture on each view.

add another UISwipeGestureRecognizer in your custom view with the direction set to downwards and call closebox method.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeBox)];
[swipeGestDown setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];

[yourCustomView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestDown];
```

Comment: your answer does address a common mis-understanding issue of UISwipeGestureRecognizer, however not the issue at hand. please see Juan Carlos Ospina Gonzalez's answer